# CSS styles not being loaded in IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

I have a very strange issue in that no CSS styles are being loaded in IE8 (maybe IE7 as well but cannot check). My site is at http://www.leavetrackapp.com/ and my master CSS file is as follows:

```
@import url("reset.css");
@import url("screen.css");
@import url("site.css");
@import url("colorbox.css");
```

The master.css file and indidivual stylesheets are accessible if I directly enter the address in the browser e.g. http://www.leavetrackapp.com/stylesheets/master.css returns the main file.

I think it's a problem with the import rules but have no idea what it could be.  Safari and Firefox work fine.

Any advice appreciated.

Thanks

Robin

Comment: `reset.css` and `screen.css` are definitely getting loaded. Are you sure this is a case of style sheets not getting loaded, as opposed to IE incompatibilities in the syntax?

Comment: +1, the IE developer tool is reading from all the css files

Comment: The dev tools are telling me that no styles are loaded.  CSS validator is throwing a lot of errors but all related to CSS3 properties (it passes if I validate at CSS3). Wonder if IE8 is choking on some CSS3 properties...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

@Guffa put me onto the right track with this: the problem is that the HTML5 elements aren't working in Internet Explorer 8 and lower.

Modernizr *would* fix this, but: http://www.modernizr.com/docs/#installing

> **Drop the script tags in the `<head>` of
>   your HTML.** For best performance, you
>   should have them follow after your
>   stylesheet references. The reason we
>   recommend placing Modernizr in the
>   head is two-fold: **the HTML5 Shiv (that
>   enables HTML5 elements in IE) must
>   execute before the `<body>`**, and if
>   you’re using any of the CSS classes
>   that Modernizr adds, you’ll want to
>   prevent a FOUC.

So, you simply need to move Modernizr from just before `</body>` to inside the `<head>` element.

Comment: Thanks - just found [this _issue_ on Github](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/issues/256) which led me to the same conclusion.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is not that the style sheets are not imported, the problem is that you are using the HTML5 `section` tag, which IE8 and earlier does not recognise.

If you change the `section` tags to `div` tags, it will work better.

Comment: I also thought it was this, but he's including Modernizr which should resolve this problem: http://www.modernizr.com/docs/#html5inie

Comment: Thanks. This was also my understanding of Modernizr. I'll replace the `section` tags etc. with non-HTML5 elements and see if that makes a difference. If so, I can't understand why Modernizr is not doing its job.