# My nav doesn't work on internet explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

The following code snippet works fine in Chrome and Mozilla browsers, but on IE8 i see only a an underdered list with no design –ave the following HTML and CSS code, and I'm not sure why. Any ideas?

```css
    nav {
    background-color: #666;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;

    }
    nav ul {
 list-style: none;
 display: inline-flex;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0 auto;
    }

    nav ul li {
 display: inline;
 margin: 0 auto;

    }

    nav a:link, nav a:visited {
 color: #FFF;
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 15px 25px 15px 25px;
 height: 20px;
 font-size: 20px;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-family: gothic;
    }

    nav a:hover, nav a:active, 
    nav .active a:link, nav .active a:visited {
 background-color: #5aada0;

    }
```

```html
    <div class="container">
  <nav>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">home</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">about</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">contact</a></li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
 </div>
```

Comment: Which IE version are you using?

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not a technical description. What doesn't work? How is it supposed to work?

Comment: Which version of IE are you talking about? Flex doesn't work on older versions so your "inline-flex" might be the issue there: http://caniuse.com/#search=flex

Comment: Voted to close as unclear.

Comment: Look at the snippet. That's how it should work. On IE8 i see only a an underdered list with no design

Comment: @CatalinSandu Look at [CSS styles not being loaded in IE8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491882/css-styles-not-being-loaded-in-ie8) and keep on Googling "css not working internet explorer 8" - Look at your developer console also. Also http://superuser.com/q/393105/633805

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML5 is not supported by IE8 so you can't use the `<nav>` tag.

Replace your nav tags with something like this:

```
<div class="nav"></div>
```